# How to lock the screen orientation for blckberry OS 4.5 Application

Tags: blackberry

How to lock orientation in blackberry OS 4.5

In blackberry OS above 5.0 it possible on following method

```
ScreenUtils.disableOrientationChange();

    // enters the event processing loop thread if required
    if (!app.isHandlingEvents())
    {
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
```

And

```
Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT);
```

But I am working on BB OS 4.5 so How it's possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789734/auto-rotation-on-blackberry-programming/7789839#7789839

Answer (score 3):

The first touchscreen device (BlackBerry Storm) came with RIM OS 4.7.

And [setAcceptableDirections](http://goo.gl/qjVAw) method was introduced in RIM SDK 4.7.

RIM SDK 4.5 does not provide control over the screen orientation.

Comment: My application is build on RIM OS 4.5 and when i used to run it on the device having OS 6.0 And I Want to Lock screen orientation. How is it possible in RIM OS 4.5 application.

Comment: As I mentioned before RIM SDK 4.5 does not support such functionality. Use preprocessor to generate your app version for different devices.