# How to handle screen rotation on Blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

What's the proper way to handle screen rotation in Blackberry? I've work with different resolutions and all I have to do is handle Bitmaps and Margins in my Fields. There's a requirement in my current project to manage screen rotation, and I don't know what's the technical approach to that.

For the records, I did a quick Google Search and all I found was information about how to disable rotation, so I'm starting to think rotation handling is kind of hard.

Comment: Overriding the `layout`/`sublayout` methods of `Field`/`Manager`/`Screen` is necessary to handle screen rotation appropriately. Any time there is a orientation change, the `layout`/`sublayout` methods of the `Screen`s and all it's childs gets called. In those method, you can check the orientation via comparing `Display.getOrientation()` with `Display.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`/`Display.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` etc. and do the resizing/modification of the UI components. If you share any one of your screen sketch for 2 different orientation, then it will help others to guide you about how to handle -

Comment: orientation change event for that screen. And from that solution you can get the idea about how to apply the solution for other screens/ui fields. Check this useful link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789734/auto-rotation-on-blackberry-programming.

Comment: Thanks @Rupak, the link from SO is very helpfull

Comment: try the below linked answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789734/auto-rotation-on-blackberry-programming/7789839#7789839

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to override sublayout. You can use this code:

```
protected void sublayout(int width, int height)
{       
    SetLayout();
    super.sublayout(width, height);
}
```

In set layout, you can set the size and position of your controls. How you do this will depend on what `FieldManager` you use. I use an `AbsoluteFieldManager` and have all my fields positioned and sized according to a percentage of the width and height of the screen. For example:

```
private void SetLayout()
{
    int screenWidth = Display.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = Display.getHeight();
    cmdOk.SetSize((int) (screenWidth * 0.2), (int) (screenHeight * 0.1));
    manager.setPosChild(cmdOk, 0, screenHeight - cmdOk.getHeight());
}
```

I hope this helps